# Search a Column of Data & Enter a Specific Value based on 2 criteria

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, search, import

I have a sheet, where I will enter a bunch of data with skus into 1 column, and have search terms somewhere else. What I want is to automatically, look at the SKU **AND** the search term, and then bring up the relevant meal customization.

Below is what my search sheet would look like & I have also entered my dream result in red, but I understand that it could be a bit too much, so just the importing of the customizations is fine.

[image]

**There is also another sheet where I would enter the customizations. The customization tab, it is where the data will be stored. So what should happen is, when I enter the items into col A & the search terms Into the first row of the SEARCH tab it should crosscheck with the customizations tab and bring in those results.**

Here is my sample sheet (with editing access): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W8L445SfSEIrrPgwPaPryC72DK_zwvyCbU6ot1ezsYM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The sample spreadsheet gives "Access denied." See [How to share a Google Sheets demo spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219).

Comment: @doubleunary sorry about that. Access given. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `filter()` with `mmult()` and `regexmatch()`, like this:

```
=iferror( 
  filter( 
    Customization!A2:E, 
    not( 
      mmult( 
        sign(not(iferror(regexmatch(Customization!B2:E, "(?i)" & B1:E1), B1:E1 = ""))), 
        transpose(sign(column(B1:E1))) 
      ) 
    ) 
  ), 
  "(no matching data)" 
)
```

This lets you search for multiple alternative terms at once, in every data column separately. The search terms are regular expressions like `no dairy|vegan`.

To format the results as a comma-separated list, use this:

```
=arrayformula( textjoin(", ", true, if(len(A1:E1), A3:E3, iferror(1/0))) )
```

See the new [Solution](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W8L445SfSEIrrPgwPaPryC72DK_zwvyCbU6ot1ezsYM/edit#gid=1898184135) sheet in your sample spreadsheet.

To learn the exact [regular expression](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/62754) syntax used by Google Sheets, see [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).

Comment: Hi @doublenary thank you for your quick response, however, this is not exactly what I'm looking for. The customization tab, it is where the data will be stored. So what should happen is, when I enter the items into col A & the search terms to the SEARCH tab it should crosscheck with the customizations tab and bring in those results. I'll add this bit to my original question, as I think it may be unclear for a bit.

Comment: Edited the answer per your requirements.

Comment: Thank you @doublenary :)